Markerclusterer deprecated warning
I now get the below error for Marker Clusterer on my Google Map using this version of the script for it <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>...
This version of the marker clusterer has been deprecated, and will be removed from service on August 1, 2024. We recommend updating your code to use @googlemaps/markerclusterer instead. More information is available at https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer.
How do I update my map to use this version?

Maybe try using a version of MarkerClusterer from one of the CDNs rather than using the one in the developers.google.com domain... or read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

I found the solution here:
Replace the old script (from developers.google.com) with this one:
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"></script>
The new class to use will be markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer (instead of MarkerClusterer)

The method call has also changed:
OLD
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(mapContact, markers, {
  imagePath: mapImagePath,
  styles: clusterStyles,
  maxZoom: 18
});

NEW
var markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({
  map: mapContact,
  markers: markers,
  imagePath: mapImagePath,
  styles: clusterStyles,
  maxZoom: 18
});

